# How to add environment variable into virtual environment when using build module?

Tags: python-3.x

### Question Background

My windows system's preferred encoding is gbk, but i want to build a project with utf-8.

So i set [utf-8 mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=utf%208#utf-8-mode) via environment variable.

### Command

```
# powershell commands
$env:PYTHONUTF8=1
python -m build --wheel
```

### Error

```
* Creating venv isolated environment...
ERROR Failed to create venv. Maybe try installing virtualenv.
·······
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 2026: illegal multibyte sequence
```

### Question

I have known the reason is that the environment variable was not added into venv isolated environment and using the option --no-isolation can skip creating venv.

Is any way to add the environment variable into venv?